# Google Storage is not a constructor error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am building an App and my objective is every time someone upload an image to firebase storage, the cloud function resize that image.

```
...
import * as Storage from '@google-cloud/storage'
const gcs = new Storage()
...

exports.resizeImage = functions.storage.object().onFinalize( async object => {
   const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
   const filePath = object.name;
   const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
   const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);
....
```

And when I tried to deploy this funtion I get this error:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Storage is not a constructor
```

I tried with "new Storage()" or just "Storage" and nothing works.

I'm newbie around here so if there's anything I forgot for you to debug this just let me know.

Thanks!

---

google-cloud/storage: 2.0.0

Node js: v8.11.4

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [API documentation for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/) suggests that you should use require to load the module:

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
```

This applied to versions of Cloud Storage prior to version 2.x.

In 2.x, there was a breaking API change.  You need to do this now:

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
```

If you would like TypeScript bindings, consider using Cloud Storage via the Firebase Admin SDK.  [The Admin SDK simply wraps the Cloud Storage module](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start), and also exports type bindings to go along with it.  It's easy to use:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp()
admin.storage().bucket(...)
```

`admin.storage()` gives you a reference to the Storage object that you're trying to work with.

Comment: Work like a charm!
Love your tutorials, thanks a lot!

Comment: Incidentally, the 2.x version of @google-cloud/storage requires you to do this now: `const { Storage } = require(...)`

Comment: I had to use it and pass my token on a constructor
```const storage = new Storage({
          keyFilename: "jorge-dashboard-v1-9dcf1f36dd34.json"
        });```

Answer (score 1):

On node 14, using commonJS with babel (although I don't think Babel was interfering here), this is how I eventually got it working on an older project bumping GCS from 1.x to 5.x:

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const gcs = new Storage({project_id});
```

didn't see this captured anywhere on the web

Answer (score 0):

Just for knowledge purpose if you guys are using the ES module approach and node 12, the below snippet would work. I couldn't make none of other syntax working~

```
import storagePackage from '@google-cloud/storage';
const { Storage } = storagePackage;
const storage = new Storage();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using electron and still don't work above solutions,try this.

```
const {Storage} = window.require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({ keyFilename: "./uploader-credentials.json" });
```

Comment: OP accepted already an answer and wrote in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52206340#comment91366089_52207774), three years earlier, it's solved...

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.